# Android crashing after trying to build a release version

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, proguard, release

The App works fine when I export it as as a debug version with no errors at all however it crashes at launch when I export it as a release version.

I've attached the error from the Android Monitor

```
10-24 03:02:02.286 17303-17303/? E/CustomizationReader: appName = Prism
10-24 03:02:02.287 17303-17303/? E/CustomizationReader: key = sku_id
10-24 03:02:02.287 17303-17303/? E/CustomizationReader: Result = 33
10-24 03:02:02.531 24402-24402/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'kotlin.jvm.internal.PropertyReference1Impl', referenced from method com.earnso.mangaworld.util.RarContentProvider.<clinit>
10-24 03:02:02.549 24402-24402/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.earnso.mangaworld, PID: 24402
                                                   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin.jvm.internal.PropertyReference1Impl
                                                       at com.earnso.mangaworld.util.RarContentProvider.<clinit>(RarContentProvider.kt)
                                                       at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1215)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5037)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4623)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4563)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1402)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-24 03:02:02.862 1130-1350/? E/cm_cmc_c: app launch:com.earnso.mangaworld
10-24 03:02:03.297 24442-24442/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.LocaleList', referenced from method com.domobile.applock.aa.a
10-24 03:02:03.491 24442-24442/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable', referenced from method com.domobile.applock.aa.r
10-24 03:02:03.769 24442-24442/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.job.JobScheduler', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcjg.z
10-24 03:02:03.770 24442-24442/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.job.JobScheduler', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcjg.a
10-24 03:02:04.062 1130-1350/? E/cm_cmc_c: app launch:com.htc.launcher
10-24 03:02:04.080 24442-24442/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager', referenced from method com.domobile.applock.service.LockService.onCreate
10-24 03:02:04.104 24442-24442/? E/eLock: startWatching
10-24 03:02:09.807 829-829/? E/StatusBar.BatteryControllerHTC: battery level = 84, plugged = true, isChargingProtection = true
10-24 03:02:12.308 739-762/? E/WindowManager: Starting window AppWindowToken{432983f0 token=Token{42f86568 ActivityRecord{42aeee78 u0 com.earnso.mangaworld/.ui.main.MainActivity t947}}} timed out
10-24 03:02:16.404 17303-17754/? E/Prism.WidgetManager: The same lists. No need to update. skip it.
10-24 03:02:19.775 829-829/? E/StatusBar.BatteryControllerHTC: battery level = 84, plugged = true, isChargingProtection = true
10-24 03:02:29.814 829-829/? E/StatusBar.BatteryControllerHTC: battery level = 84, plugged = true, isChargingProtection = true
10-24 03:02:31.433 1130-24563/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x63b441f8 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x68dd2940 arg=0x0
10-24 03:02:31.438 1130-24563/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x63b441f8 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
10-24 03:02:39.811 829-829/? E/StatusBar.BatteryControllerHTC: battery level = 85, plugged = true, isChargingProtection = true
10-24 03:02:42.729 31423-31423/? E/SS3StatQuery: ScreenSaver3Activity changeScreenStat false
10-24 03:02:47.732 17303-18963/? E/Prism.MastheadStatePro_: uri: content://com.htc.launcher.masthead_state/visibility
10-24 03:02:47.741 17303-24059/? E/Prism.MastheadStatePro_: uri: content://com.htc.launcher.masthead_state/visibility
10-24 03:02:47.965 739-1035/? E/RemoteViews: ANR Warning,RemoteViews can only be used once ,if not ,it may cause ANR in hosts such as Laucher,SystemUI. keys for search <ANR Exception MSG   History>
10-24 03:02:48.218 17303-24721/? E/Prism.MastheadStatePro_: uri: content://com.htc.launcher.masthead_state/panelstatus?notify=false
10-24 03:02:49.782 829-829/? E/StatusBar.BatteryControllerHTC: battery level = 85, plugged = true, isChargingProtection = true
10-24 03:02:59.810 829-829/? E/StatusBar.BatteryControllerHTC: battery level = 85, plugged = true, isChargingProtection = true
```

This is the app level gradle file.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

if (file("custom.gradle").exists()) {
    apply from: "custom.gradle"
}

ext {
    // Git is needed in your system PATH for these commands to work.
    // If it's not installed, you can return a random value as a workaround
    getCommitCount = {
        return 'git rev-list --count HEAD'.execute().text.trim()
        // return "1"
    }

    getGitSha = {
        return 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute().text.trim()
        // return "1"
    }

    getBuildTime = {
        def df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'")
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
        return df.format(new Date())
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    publishNonDefault true
    dexOptions {
        // Prevent OutOfMemory with MultiDex during the build phase
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.earnso.mangaworld"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        versionCode 26
        versionName "0.6.3"

        buildConfigField "String", "COMMIT_COUNT", "\"${getCommitCount()}\""
        buildConfigField "String", "COMMIT_SHA", "\"${getGitSha()}\""
        buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"${getBuildTime()}\""
        buildConfigField "boolean", "INCLUDE_UPDATER", "false"

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            //versionNameSuffix "-${getCommitCount()}"
            //applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            //shrinkResources true
            multiDexEnabled true
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        standard {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "INCLUDE_UPDATER", "true"
        }
        fdroid {
        }
        dev {
            minSdkVersion 16
            resConfigs "en", "xxhdpi"
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

dependencies {

    // Modified dependencies

    // Android support library
    final support_library_version = '26.1.0'
    // ReactiveX

    // Network client

    // REST
    final retrofit_version = '2.3.0'
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:$retrofit_version"
    // JSON

    // YAML

    // JavaScript engine

    // Disk

    // HTML parser

    // Job scheduling

    // Changelog

    // Database

    // Model View Presenter
    final nucleus_version = '3.0.0'
    compile "info.android15.nucleus:nucleus:$nucleus_version"
    compile "info.android15.nucleus:nucleus-support-v7:$nucleus_version"
    // Dependency injection

    // Image library
    final glide_version = '4.2.0'
    compile "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"
    compile "com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:$glide_version"
    kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glide_version"
    // Transformations

    // Logging

    // Crash reports

    // Sort

    // UI
    compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.7') {
        exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-v13"
    }
    // Conductor

    // RxBindings
    final rxbindings_version = '1.0.1'
    compile "com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-kotlin:$rxbindings_version"
    compile "com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-appcompat-v7-kotlin:$rxbindings_version"
    compile "com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-support-v4-kotlin:$rxbindings_version"
    compile "com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-recyclerview-v7-kotlin:$rxbindings_version"
    // Tests
    final robolectric_version = '3.1.4'
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:$robolectric_version"
    testCompile "org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:$robolectric_version"
    testCompile "org.robolectric:shadows-play-services:$robolectric_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    final coroutines_version = '0.19.1'
    compile 'com.github.inorichi:subsampling-scale-image-view:01e5385'
    compile 'com.github.inorichi:tachimage:68cd311'
    compile 'com.github.inorichi:junrar-android:634c1f5'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxrelay:rxrelay:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.f2prateek.rx.preferences:rx-preferences:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.pwittchen:reactivenetwork:0.7.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.github.salomonbrys.kotson:kotson:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.github.bmoliveira:snake-yaml:v1.18-android'
    compile 'com.squareup.duktape:duktape-android:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:disklrucache:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.seven332:unifile:1.0.0'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
    compile 'com.evernote:android-job:1.1.11'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.changeloglib:changelog:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.pushtorefresh.storio:sqlite:1.13.0'
    compile 'uy.kohesive.injekt:injekt-core:1.16.1'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.2'
    compile 'com.github.gpanther:java-nat-sort:natural-comparator-1.1'
    compile 'com.dmitrymalkovich.android:material-design-dimens:1.4'
    compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.android-process-button:library:1.0.4'
    compile 'eu.davidea:flexible-adapter:5.0.0-rc1'
    compile 'com.nononsenseapps:filepicker:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.amulyakhare:TextDrawable:558677e'
    compile 'me.zhanghai.android.systemuihelper:library:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.nightlynexus.viewstatepageradapter:viewstatepageradapter:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.github.mthli:Slice:v1.2'
    compile 'com.bluelinelabs:conductor:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.github.inorichi:conductor-support-preference:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.1'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$support_library_version"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_library_version"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$support_library_version"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$support_library_version"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_library_version"
    compile "com.android.support:preference-v7:$support_library_version"
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$support_library_version"
    compile "com.android.support:customtabs:$support_library_version"
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_version"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
}

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines 'enable'
    }
}

// add support for placeholders in resource files
//https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69224
def replacePlaceholdersInFile(basePath, fileName, placeholders) {
    def file = new File(basePath, fileName);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        logger.quiet("Unable to replace placeholders in " + file.toString() + ". File cannot be found.")
        return;
    }

    logger.debug("Replacing placeholders in " + file.toString())
    logger.debug("Placeholders: " + placeholders.toString())

    def content = file.getText('UTF-8')

    placeholders.each { entry ->
        content = content.replaceAll("\\\$\\{${entry.key}\\}", entry.value)
    }

    file.write(content, 'UTF-8')
}

afterEvaluate {
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.processResources.doFirst {
                // prepare placeholder map from manifestPlaceholders including applicationId placeholder
                def placeholders = variant.mergedFlavor.manifestPlaceholders + [applicationId: variant.applicationId]

                replacePlaceholdersInFile(resDir, 'xml-v25/shortcuts.xml', placeholders)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Building on the debug version works completely fine but as soon as I transfer it to release version it starts crashing.

Comment: Are you using proguard? This looks like it might be a code stripping issue.

Comment: @emerssso I'm new to android and yes proguard is used however I set minifyEnabled to false and tried it again, the same. So am I doing something wrong? How can I disable proguard completely?

Comment: If you have `minifyEnabled false` then proguard is off, so that can't be it. Can you include your `build.gradle` file for the app? It's probably an issue there...

Comment: @emerssso I've attached the gradle file. can you please take a look at it?

Comment: Your gradle file looks ok, what version of android are you testing on? Could be a multidex issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close Android Studio Completely. Clean and Rebuild the Project.